# WPF Image в Border и отрицательный Margin у Image

Tags: wpf, xaml

Почему картинка вылезает слева из Border?

```
<Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Height="32" 
        Width="32" 
        Margin="3">
  <Image Source="БлаБлаБла.png" Width="384" Height="32" Margin="-32 0 0 0"/>
</Border>
```

P.S. Точнее вопрос вот в чем, как мне усеч картинку с лева (с права) без кода c# (из коментария)

Comment: А где должен вылезать?

Comment: Margin="-32 0 0 0"

Comment: Дак почему за рамки бордера вылезает то? и именно с лева

Comment: Точнее вопрос вот в чем, как мне усеч картинку с лева (с права) без кода c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вылазит за рамки бордера ваш рисунок потому что вы указали отрицательный margin - который собственно и определяет сдвиг элемента. Если же вы хотите усечь картинку, то это делается с помощью свойства Image.Clip. Например:

```
<Image Source="БлаБлаБла.png" Width="384" Height="32">
    <Image.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="32, 0, 384, 32"></RectangleGeometry>
    </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

Comment: Вот не поверишь. только что нашел через гугл =) Опредил однако..